# Custom type in asp net core mvc controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I have created the following type in my MVC 6 application:

```
public class EncryptedType
{
    ...
}
```

I have a controller method as follows:

```
public IActionResult Index(EncryptedType id)
{
    ...
}
```

So given the the url would be something like:

http://localhost/Area1/Controller1/Index/fgf23237dsd

Where the EncryptedType class can handle converting to/from a string.

Currently the id is defaulting to the parameterless constructor value.  What do I need to do to make this automatically convert the string id on the url to an instance?

Naturally I could use a string but I just feel having an explicit type to represent the type in the method is more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I guess today I have my googling head on, so was able to work through a number of Stack Overflows and Microsoft docs.  There are essentially 4 parts to wire up.  These are:

1. IModelBinder implementation
2. IModelBinderProvider implementation
3. Mvc Service Registration Options
4. Attribute on the Controller Action

**IModelBinder implementation**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

public class EncryptedTypeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(EncryptedType))
        {
            EncryptedType decodedEncryptedTypeParameter;

            ValueProviderResult value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.FieldName);
            string theStringToConvertToEncryptedType = value.FirstValue;

            // add the custom convert from string to your type here, and set on the bindingContext.Result.  We still return 
            // this value from the method wrapped in a Task.
            if (EncryptedType.TryParse(theStringToConvertToEncryptedType, out decodedEncryptedTypeParameter))
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(decodedEncryptedTypeParameter);
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            }

            return Task.FromResult(bindingContext.Result);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(ModelBindingResult.Failed());
    }
}
```

**IModelBinderProvider implementation**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

public class EncryptedTypeModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        return new EncryptedTypeModelBinder();
    }
}
```

**Mvc Service Registration Options**

```
services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(a => 
    a.ModelBinderProviders.Add(new EncryptedTypeModelBinderProvider()));
```

**Attribute on the Controller Action**

```
public IActionResult Index(
    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(EncryptedTypeModelBinder))] EncryptedType id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work out of the box.
For example, if this is EncryptedType:

```
public class EncryptedType
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Then, if your query string looks something like this:

http://localhost:5000/Index?Id=1&Name=MyName

The data from the query string will be parsed automatically to an instance of this class.

It is not possible to instansiate the class with an other constructor than the default one.
Please look at the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding

There is a section there that states the following:

> In order for binding to happen the class must have a public default
>   constructor and member to be bound must be public writable properties.
>   When model binding happens the class will only be instantiated using
>   the public default constructor, then the properties can be set.

Comment: I have updated the question with a url to try and explain a bit better. Its to take the id in the route definition and convert it to my type.

Comment: I have updated my answer after your clarification. It is not possible to makke the model binding with a constructor that is not the default parameterless one.

Comment: Just curious, but aspnet handles built in types like strings, ints, and guids I do believe.  Not looked at this for a bit, but was hoping for a hook to put in your own types.